Difficulty mounting external drive after certain boots
I have a RasPi 4 connected to a 12TB EXT4 hard drive in a Sabrent cage hub which I use for an OpenMediaVault NAS. The drive worked fine for about a month until its file system started to go missing in OMV, either completely or visible and unmounted with the status "missing." I've tried automatically rebooting every 12 hours or manual restarts (the Pi and cage have separate power buttons) and cannot tell which method is more reliable. I've noticed the block device sometimes changes between sda(1) and sdb(1) and other times no partitions are listed in fdisk or df. Sometimes the drive is SMART compatible (and passes), other times it says it isn't. I've had error messages after the following commands:
**(1) [2024-11-02] sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | less**

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (   87) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   132   132   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       96
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   155   155   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       425 (Average 425)

**(2) [2024-11-02] dmesg**

[ 1197.499680] critical target error, dev sda, sector 23437770624 op 0x0:(READ)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2

[ 1197.499692] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 2929721328, async page                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              read

[Note: no errors in dmesg as of 2024-12-02]

**(3) [2024-12-01] sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda**

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error

**(4) [2024-12-01] sudo fsck /dev/sda**

fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device> [Note: this option timed out]
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device> [Note: this option timed out]

**(5) [2024-12-01] sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda**

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)

**(6) [2024-12-01] sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda1 --test=short -T permissive**

SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability

Error Counter logging not supported

No Self-tests have been logged

It appears most likely to unmount after I'm away from home and don't perform updates for awhile (I have not set up a reverse proxy for the RasPi in general, only for a Plex server). I can't tell if the hard drive is about to fail or if this is all just an issue with booting.

Perhaps the Sabrent cage hub takes too long to power up and stabilize. Try powering it up first, or delay the Pi power.

Regarding the block device name: the sata driver in the kernel didnt register that the drive had disconnected, probably due to the error. So when you cycle power, the driver still thinks the previous name is in use, so provides the next available name.

It could be that the drive is failing, it could be that the usb to sata adapter is failing or isn't quite compatible with Raspberry pi hardware. It could also be insufficient power to the RPi--you really need high quality power supplies for RPi 4s and 5s, especially to be able to satisfy momentary spikes is power demand.

For the block device, how do I keep it to /dev/sda? And for the power, I use a PSU with Input: 180-240V 50/60Hz 0.8 A and Output: 5V --- 3000 mA. What would you recommend? Is there a command to measure power spikes?

I've been having to manually reboot the drive and Pi to deal with errors like the mapped drive saying the name is misspelled or the network subfolder saying "A device attached to the system is not functioning." I should mention the drive has an external supply, but would it still be delivering excessive power to the Pi during loads? I still would like to know how to lock the block device name, especially since I plan to add a second identical drive for backups.
